# SelectizeJS: Custom tags not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm trying use Selectize to let users choose tags from a list of tags but also be able to add new tags.

Here is the code:

```
$("#input").selectize({
  delimiter: ',',
  persist: true,
  options: [{text: 'A', value: 'A'}, {text: 'B', value: 'B'}],
  create: function(input) {
    return { value: input, text: input }
  }
});
```

If I select A, B and a new tag C they all get saved in the database as `A,B,C`, but when the page loads again only `A` and `B` are shown even if the original textarea contains also `C`.

It's like `Selectize` only recognizes the items in `options` only and ignored any other tag.

Comment: I think you should set `options` to the data stored in DB, because if you do it like in the code you provided it will always consist of 2 elements (A, B)

Comment: @mic4al But what about displaying a list of tags, in this case, A and B.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Because It's a tags input, tags can be added dynamically and users have a default list of tags available.